# How to update a column using another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a dataframe that keeps track of the number of public schools opened between 2010-2016.

```
StatusType  County  2010 ...2016    OpenYear    ClosedYear
1   Closed  Alameda 0        0        2005        2015.0
2   Active  Alameda 0        0        2006         NaN
3   Closed  Alameda 0        0        2008        2015.0
4   Active  Alameda 0        0        2011         NaN
5   Active  Alameda 0        0        2011         NaN
6   Active  Alameda 0        0        2012         NaN
7   Closed  Alameda 0        0        1980        1989.0
8   Active  Alameda 0        0        1980         NaN
9   Active  Alameda 0        0        1980         NaN
```

I want to update the 2010-2016 columns to keep track of the number of schools open per year. For example, the first school in the dataframe opens in 2005 and closes in 2015. The iterator should check "ClosedYear" column and add 1 to all columns' rows' values < 2015 (2010,2011...,2014). If the "ClosedYear" column shows "NaN", then starting at the year in "OpenYear" column, add 1 to all columns' rows' values >= "OpenYear" (ex: school#4, columns[2011,2012...,2016] +1 & column[2010] no change)

I was thinking about using "apply" to apply a function to the dataframe. But that might not be the most efficient way to solve the problem. Need help figuring out how to make this work! Thanks!

**Extra Step:**
After finishing the counts, I want to group the year columns by county. I'm leaning towards using the "groupby" w/sum function to sum up the open school counts per county per year. If someone could add that with the answer to the question above, would be very helpful.

Expected Output:

```
StatusType       County 2010 ...2016    OpenYear    ClosedYear
    1   Closed  Alameda 1        0        2005        2015.0
    2   Active  Alameda 1        1        2006         NaN
    3   Closed  Alameda 1        0        2008        2015.0
    4   Active  Alameda 0        1        2011         NaN
    5   Active  Alameda 0        1        2011         NaN
    6   Active  Alameda 0        1        2012         NaN
    7   Closed  Alameda 0        0        1980        1989.0
    8   Active  Alameda 1        1        1980         NaN
    9   Active  Alameda 1        1        1980         NaN
```

Comment: can you add an example of your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like there should be a way to do this without using a `for loop` but, I cannot think of it atm, so here's my solution:

```
# Read Example data
from io import StringIO # This only works python 3+
df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(
"""StatusType  County    OpenYear    ClosedYear
Closed      Alameda   2005        2015.0
Active      Alameda   2006         NaN
Closed      Alameda   2008        2015.0
Active      Alameda   2011         NaN
Active      Alameda   2011         NaN
Active      Alameda   2012         NaN
Closed      Alameda   1980        1989.0
Active      Alameda   1980         NaN
Active      Alameda   1980         NaN"""))

# For each year
for year in range(2010, 2016+1):
    # Create a column of 0s
    df[str(year)] = 0
    # Where the year is between OpenYear and ClosedYear (or closed year is NaN) set it to 1
    df.loc[(df['OpenYear'] <= year) & (pd.isna(df['ClosedYear']) | (df['ClosedYear'] >= year)), str(year)] = int(1)

print(df.to_string)
```

Output:

```
  StatusType   County  OpenYear  ClosedYear  2010  2011  2012  2013  2014  2015  2016
0     Closed  Alameda      2005      2015.0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0
1     Active  Alameda      2006         NaN     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
2     Closed  Alameda      2008      2015.0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0
3     Active  Alameda      2011         NaN     0     1     1     1     1     1     1
4     Active  Alameda      2011         NaN     0     1     1     1     1     1     1
5     Active  Alameda      2012         NaN     0     0     1     1     1     1     1
6     Closed  Alameda      1980      1989.0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
7     Active  Alameda      1980         NaN     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
8     Active  Alameda      1980         NaN     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

(PS: I'm not quite sure what you were trying to do with the `groupby`)

Comment: `pub_s.loc[(pub_s['OpenYear'] <= year) & ((pub_s['ClosedYear'].isnull()) | (pub_s['ClosedYear'] >= year)), year] += int(1)`

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is really a need to create those intermediate columns, you can get the counts directly with a `groupby` and `.size` Depending upon whether you want to include the closing year, change the inequalities from `<=` to `<`. If you want to group this by county also you can do that in the same step.

Here's the starting `df`

```
  StatusType   County  OpenYear  ClosedYear
1     Closed  Alameda      2005      2015.0
2     Active  Alameda      2006         NaN
3     Closed  Alameda      2008      2015.0
4     Active  Alameda      2011         NaN
5     Active  Alameda      2011         NaN
6     Active  Alameda      2012         NaN
7     Closed  Alameda      1980      1989.0
8     Active  Alameda      1980         NaN
9     Active  Alameda      1980         NaN

import pandas as pd
year_list = [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016]
df_list = []

for year in year_list:
    group = ((df.ClosedYear.isnull()) | (df.ClosedYear >= year)) & (df.OpenYear <= year)
    n_schools = df.groupby([group, df.County]).size()[True]
    df_list.append(pd.DataFrame({'n_schools':n_schools, 'year': year}))

ndf = pd.concat(df_list)
#         n_schools  year
#County                  
#Alameda          5  2010
#Alameda          7  2011
#Alameda          8  2012
#Alameda          8  2013
#Alameda          8  2014
#Alameda          8  2015
#Alameda          6  2016
```

Comment: I believe your `group` would count a school that was open from `2012` to `NaN` as being open in all years.

Comment: No Worries, it took me like 30 tries to get them correct.

Comment: `df = df.groupby(['County']).sum()`